# Is there a way to memory-map files in Java that are larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mmap, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

[`FileChannel#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)), which is used to map a file (i.e., initiate a memory map), takes a `long` as length parameter.

Yet, [the documentation on `FileChannel#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) says the following:

> size - The size of the region to be mapped; must be non-negative and no greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE

First of all, why do they use a long in the first place if they only allow values up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?
Is it somehow possible to map files larger than that at once?

For example, if I would like to map a 10GB file, I would like to write something like this (which ends up in an `InvalidArgumentException` due to the too large length):

```
long length = 10_000_000_000;
MappedByteBuffer buffer = (new RandomAccessFile("./memory.map", "rw")).getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
```

Do I have to create consecutive memory maps for that, e.g., 5 memory maps each mapping 2GB of the given file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileChannel#map will return an instance of [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html),
(MappedByteBuffer) and if you look at it, you can see that it's methods exclusively use `int` to index the data, e.g:

> abstract byte  get(int index) Absolute get method.

Which defines the limit for `map` itself, too.

So, you would have to either map your file piece by piece or use some existing library, e.g. https://github.com/xerial/larray, to map a bigger file, which uses JNI to map files > 2GB, and provides it's own Buffer abstraction, using `long` data pointers.

One more option is to use Unsafe operations, like described [here](http://nyeggen.com/post/2014-05-18-memory-mapping-%3E2gb-of-data-in-java/).

Answer (score 2):

JDK14 offers a new solution to this limitation of the FileChannel API with the introduction of the Foreign-Memory Access API (JEP 383) preview. See the [MemorySegment.mapFromPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.incubator.foreign/jdk/incubator/foreign/MemorySegment.html#mapFromPath(java.nio.file.Path,long,java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode)) method to get started.